# Difference between NETBIOS, host name and computer name?

Tags: networking, hostname, netbios

In windows if you go to **Computer->Properties->Advanced System Settings->Computer Name**, you can change the computer name, let's say from `MYCOMPUTER` to `LEDZEPPELIN`.

- This changes the (1) computer name to `LEDZEPPELIN`.
- It also changes the (2) hostname to `LEDZEPPELIN` when I pop 192.168.1.1 into the url.
- This also allows me to run the (3) NETBIOS lookup from a different computer connected to the same router that runs linux.  I'll pass `LEDZEPPELIN` as the NETBIOS name.

```
nmblookup LEDZEPPELIN
```

and it returns the ip address.  I'm confused, are all three similar?

If you could provide a helpful analogy to aid in my understanding (like this: [Difference between host name and domain name](https://superuser.com/questions/59093/difference-between-host-name-and-domain-name)) that would be totally awesome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A domain is something you will experience on a work network rather than a home environment generally speaking.

imagine:
computer name john
netbios name is usually also john (but has stricter naming restrictions)

on a domain your full computer name may be `john.company.local` for example

the `company.local` bit being the name of the domain itself.

netbios is old way of resolving names and in many ways is not used, however is kept there in the OS for backwards compatibility.

your netbios name and computer name for all intents and purposes is nearly always the same.

out of curiosity, is there a specific piece of this from the article you linked that you don't understand and I can try and further clarify.

Comment: Your answer is simple and straightforward.  Just in case LZ is up for a little reading here is a little snack http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/difference-between-netbios-and-host-name/

Comment: I was mostly confused about what the computer name meant, but you answered that by saying on a domain it would generally include the domain name itself.  Since I'm on a home network, the computer name resolves to the host name

Comment: yea the computer name is used in windows networking / applications to give you a friendly name, instead of having to remember 192.168.0.1 I know my pc is called sniper-pc ;)

Answer (score 4):

Windows has a ***host-name*** which is provided by user at the time of installation.The same host name is resolved into ***computer-name*** by adding two letters "PC". Then the same name is added as ***Net-BIOS*** name by adding a new special character ($) at the end of host name. All the 3 names change by changing ***host-name***.

Comment: Any idea what the longer non-NETBIOS hostname is referred to in order to differentiate them?