# What is the difference between "Computer name" and "Full Computer Name"

Tags: windows, computer-name

When I'm looking at "System Information" on `Windows OS` I can see two fields which have the same values. `Computer name` and `Full computer name`.
[image]

So what is the difference between "`Computer name`" and "Full computer name"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between NETBIOS, host name and computer name?](http://superuser.com/questions/368602/difference-between-netbios-host-name-and-computer-name)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're part of a domain, the Full computer name would include your computer name with the domain name appended to it.

For example:

If I join a domain called `mydomain.local` and my computer name is `MyPC`, Computer name would show `MyPC` and Full computer name would show `MyPC.mydomain.local`. Because you're not part of a domain, both entries just show your computer name.

If you added a server to your network, you could enable `Active Directory` and `Domain Controller` services on that server to allow computers on your network to join the domain it controls. Once connected to the domain, the Full computer name entry would show your computer name including the domain name you chose when you setup the (Hypothetical) Server.

Answer (score 2):

A computer name in windows is just a name of computer like you name anything.
However a a full computer name is fully qualified domain name used in troubleshooting process of network.

Regards
David.

Comment: ComputerName.DomainorWorkgroup.com as an example of a FQDN.