# What is a hostname versus a computer name versus a subdomain versus www?

Tags: networking, hostname, subdomain, www

I was searching for understanding what is the “www” at the beginning of so many web addresses in the Internet. I read in somewhere that “www” is called “hostname”.

The world “hostname” made me go a step further in searching, I read so many threads and articles but I am still confused about that.

So I decided to ask some related questions here to make it clear and I need solid and comprehensive answers please.

1. **“hostname” vs. computer name:** Is the “hostname” the same as the computer name, if its true, suppose that my computer is a web server and my computer name is “Robin” so is it correct to conclude that a hypothetical web site would be something like: `Robin.websitename.com`?
2. **“hostname” vs. subdomain:** If “mail” in `mail.google.com` and “developers” in `developers.google.com` are called subdomains why is `en` in `en.wikipedia.org` called [hostname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname)? What is the difference between host name and subdomain?
3. **What is the relation between host name and fully qualified domain name (FQDN)?**
4. **What is the “www” in URL of some web sites?** As you know Google’s web address is `www.google.com` but we have many web sites without “www” for example: `superuser.com` and `en.wikipedia.org`. I read in this [article](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/question180.htm) that “www” is just a declarative thing not more and is not related to the concept of hostname. Do you verify that?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The best way to explain the differences between these different items—that are related but different—is to break it down by example. Think of networks like a tree:

- There is a trunk that separates into major branches.
- Branches which in turn separate into smaller branches.
- Smaller branches eventually leading to individual leaves.

The “trunk” and “branches” are “domains” and “subdomains” and the leaves are individual devices, like computers. So let’s start there.

- **A “computer name” is strictly a local convention:** I have a computer named `giacomo1968`. This computer name is simply the name I have assigned my local machine. Nobody outside of my LAN will know this computer name; this is strictly a local setting.
- **A “hostname” (aka “nodename”) is a network identifier:** If I wanted to publicly advertise my local computer to others, I would have to attach a “hostname” to the IP address of my computer. The “hostname” doesn’t really have to have anything to do with the computer name, but many times administrators like to use the same name to make things easier to understand. Also a “hostname” doesn’t always mean the computer is exposed to the Internet; it’s just an easy way to let others on your network where/what your computer is. As [Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname); emphasis is mine:

> In computer networking, a hostname (archaically nodename) is **a
> label that is assigned to a device connected to a computer network** and
> that is used to identify the device in various forms of electronic
> communication such as the World Wide Web, e-mail or Usenet.

- **A fully qualified domain name (FQDN) is just that; a fully qualified domain name:** Now that might seem confusing but you need to think of it this way: It just means in the great scheme of things, what is the actual “path” to get to a computer. So let’s say I have my computer named `giacomo1968` and it has a hostname on my LAN that is `giacomo1968`. Within the context of my LAN, that `giacomo1968` is my computer name, and is my “hostname” and can *possibly* be considered my “fully qualified domain name” depending on my LAN architecture. Meaning let’s say my office LAN has other nodes in it like, `first_floor` and `second_floor` and my “hostname” of `giacomo1968` is on the `second_floor` network. Well, if that were the case, then my LAN-based “fully qualified domain name” would be `giacomo1968.second_floor` and that is it. But let’s say I worked at a big company named “big_company.com” and my computer were somehow exposed to the world. Then in that case, my WAN-based “fully qualified domain name” could be `giacomo1968.second_floor.big_company.com` or maybe even just `giacomo1968.big_company.com` if the network administrator didn’t want to be hassled with the “second_floor” designation. Again, as [Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name); emphasis is mine:

> A fully qualified domain name (FQDN), sometimes also referred to as an
> absolute domain name, is a domain name that specifies its exact
> location in the tree hierarchy of the Domain Name System (DNS). It
> specifies all domain levels, including the top-level domain and the
> root zone. **A fully qualified domain name is distinguished by its lack
> of ambiguity: it can be interpreted only in one way.**

- **The “www” in some website names is a “hostname” designation that is historical in nature:** Basically, back in the 1990s when the world wide web was still in it’s infancy, networks had many different services attached to them. And mainly in an academic context. So there would be a place like `whattsamattau.edu` and that school would have FTP services on `ftp.whattsamattau.edu`, email on `mail.whattsamattau.edu` and so on… So when the world wide web came along, they would just have placed the web server on `www.whattsamattau.edu`. Nowadays, everyone—and seemingly everything in the world—has a website. And many people just register domains just for the web service. So the historic convention of `www` is discarded in many cases. Many people have websites without `www` but will still have accommodations to redirect `www` traffic to the main, non-`www` hostname. But technically speaking, `www` can still be considered a hostname.
- **BONUS (Never Asked But Mentioned/Implied): What is a “subdomain” in the great scheme of things:** A subdomain is basically just a child of a parent domain/hostname. So in my example of `giacomo1968.big_company.com` the `giacomo1968` can be considered a subdomain of `big_company.com` and `big_company` in that can be considered to be the “domain” with `.com` being the top-level domain (TLD). Yet again, [as Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System); emphasis is mine:

> In the Domain Name System (DNS) hierarchy, **a subdomain is a domain
> that is part of a larger domain.**

Now after drafting all of this, it can be confusing. Many computer names are hostnames are fully-qualified domain names and in some cases they could be subdomains. It’s all a matter of context. And looking at articles online the words “domain,” “host” and “node” are used fairly loose and fast all over the place. So in my opinion, many uses of these terms are synonymous.

Which also helps to explain your confusion in item number 2:

> If “mail” in `mail.google.com` and “developers” in
> `developers.google.com` are called subdomains why is `en` in
> `en.wikipedia.org` called hostname? What is the difference
> between host name and subdomain?

The `en.wikipedia.org` is a subdomain *and* a hostname. The `en` in the `en.wikipedia.org` is a subdomain of the domain name `wikipedia.org`. And `en.wikipedia.org` is in itself a hostname since `en.wikipedia.org` has an IP address connected to it and thus a computer connected to that IP address as well. Meaning the `en` itself is semantically considered a subdomain, but it is also a hostname because there is a host (computer) connected to the IP address connected to `en.wikipedia.org`. So knowing that `mail.google.com` and `developers.google.com` are hostnames as well which are both subdomains of `google.com`.

To possibly make things clearer think of it like this; let’s use the non-existant subdomain `fakename.wikipedia.org` as an example:

- The `org` in `fakename.wikipedia.org` is a [top-level domain (TLD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain). As a top-level domain it does not resolve to an IP address. Thus it is not a hostname. It is simply a naming convention.
- The `wikipedia.org` in `fakename.wikipedia.org` is a [domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name) and it has the *potential* to be a hostname as well if it is connected to an IP address and resolves to a computer when one goes to `wikipedia.org`.
- The `fakename` in `fakename.wikipedia.org` is a subdomain name since it is a child domain of `wikipedia.org` in the context of the domain name itself. It can be a hostname if it connected to an IP address and resolves to a computer when one goes to `fakename.wikipedia.org`.

If you ping `fakename.wikipedia.org` you are attempting to ping the `fakename` subdomain of `wikipedia.org`. If that ping dies — which it most likely will since it is fake — that means that the host is down or it does not exist. If it dies with an IP address connected to it, that would mean the hostname `fakename.wikipedia.org` is down. If the ping dies with 100% no IP address connected to it, them it would mean that the subdomain `fakename.wikipedia.org` is an invalid hostname.

Yes, this can all be confusing. But what it boils down to is the difference between what a domain/subdomain is in the context of DNS entries versus what domain/subdomain is in the context of having a host/computer connected to it.

So if this all started with your curiosity about `www`, that is a historic hostname/nodename/subdomain that is not really used as a convention as much anymore but is still so commonly used that many sites have some accommodations in place to “catch” requests to `www` and redirect them to the main hostname of a website.

Answer (score 5):

1. Hostname is an attribute of a system stored locally on that system.  "Computer name" is what Windows uses to refer to the hostname.
2. A subdomain is a DNS concept.  In DNS, domain names (domains for short) can be authoritative or non-authoritative - if they are non-authoritative, that means another server "handles" that domain.  So in a domain such as `www.mysite.invalid` - one thing that could happen is that the root domain refers a lookup to a server handling the `invalid` domain, which then further refers the lookup to a server handling the `mysite` domain, etc.

   Your system might keep track of the domain it thinks it's on as well as a locally managed hostname.
3. You can change your computer's local hostname, but this won't automatically update any DNS server pointed to your machine unless you have software specifically doing that (such as Active Directory in a corporate Windows environment).

   Many DHCP clients are also capable of changing a computer's local hostname in response to a DHCP response from a DHCP server.

   Typically a system's internal hostname and external DNS name will match, but they don't have to, though 99% of time you want them to.

   You can set your computer's hostname to the same as its full external DNS, and it usually makes sense to do so.
4. Let's say you run a network somewhere, and have a DNS domain for it, such as `mynetwork.invalid`.  Let's also say you are running your own DNS server, so any DNS requests for anything ending in `mynetwork.invalid` come to your DNS server.  Now, let's say you have a couple servers, such as FTP, a Web server, etc.  You'll have to create a record on your DNS server for each machine, and `www` was more a less a standard for Web servers in a network.  So then `ftp.mynetwork.invalid` would point to your FTP server, and `www.mynetwork.invalid` would point to your Web server, etc.

   You might choose to have the plain old `mynetwork.invalid` pointing to the most common service you run, such as the Web server, to save people from typing a lot and make your URLs look better, but if someone enters simply `mynetwork.invalid` on an FTP client, there will be problems.

   However, most modern sites are only running one service, not a bunch of servers running a bunch of different servers.  So then a shortcut is taken - `mynetwork.invalid` is the only one used, and you might create a second DNS entry `www.mynetwork.invalid` pointing to the same IP just for compatibility or those who are used to typing it.

Comment: Just a suggestion: your answer assumes a certain level of knowledge about networking, how it all works, related terminology, etc.  The OP obviously lacks all of that.  Can you "dumb down" your answer to plain language, explain terminology, etc.?  Your answer is fairly thorough, but understandable only to people who don't need the answer to this question.

Comment: I think one of my questions has left unanswered.In wiki example: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname "en" called "hostname" not subdomain.But in many the same structures like developers.google.com "first part" called subdomain!! Now I want to know which is correct? I think wiki example is wrong, what is your idea?

Comment: To say "hostname" in this situation - you are emphasizing that the "en" is not a subdomain, it's a computer you connect to.  It's local hostname is probably "en" but you can't tell just from the FQDN, but it doesn't matter since you don't need to know the local hostname to connect.

Comment: @ultrasawblade : you mean that by looking at this structure :firstpart.websitename.com, its not possible to conclude that "the firstpart" is a host name or a subdomain,am I right?

Comment: To be absolutely sure you want to use a utility like `dig` - you can play with an online version here: http://www.digwebinterface.com.  As an exercise, enter `edu`, then `mit.edu`, then `www.mit.edu` and compare the results.  "SOA" is a DNS record that says "another server handles anything in this subdomain" - "A", "PTR", and "CNAME" records are (pointers/aliases to) names/IPs of actual hosts.

Comment: Its a great tool, results was different between mit.edu and www.mit.edu, It means that the same website is running on different machines or hosts But in the case of wikipedia, different hostnames(wikipedia.org, en.wikipedia.org,it.wikipedia.org) return the same Ip address and If I am right , it means that different subdomains  are hosted on the same machine.thank you

Comment: @fixer1234 - It's hard to explain properly IMHO without going over the basics of DNS.  The main point I'm trying to make is that the local hostname and DNS are really two different things and aren't really connected to one another, even if a like terminology is used with both concepts.

Comment: @ultrasawblade :thank you sir, as you said its necessary to know the basics of DNS  for further understanding but your answer helped me so much, thank you for your time, it was hard for me to choose the best answer but honestly I want to say  you helped me,really thanks, the following link helped me for better understanding:                  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6410c5d8-5106-4f40-a4ff-e6cca33aabad/what-is-a-hostname-versus-a-computer-name-versus-a-subdomain-versus-www?forum=winserverDS#6410c5d8-5106-4f40-a4ff-e6cca33aabad

Answer (score 1):

I think that for all practical purposes on the public internet, a Domain name is the registered domain. ie:

- example.com
- dell.com

Hosts are addressable entities in a domain, eg:

- ftp.example.com
- mail.example.com
- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Sub-domains are NOT host names (despite what most documents on the internet say).
in the following examples of a unique "fully-qualified domain name" (FQDN), the words "accounts" and "marketing" are sub-domains:

- [www.accounts.example.com](http://www.accounts.example.com)
- [www.marketing.example.com](http://www.marketing.example.com)