# Windows 10/PC name vs Computer name

Tags: windows-10

What is the difference between the computer name and PC name in Windows 10. In windows 10 these settings are different and I’m trying to set up a few Windows VM’s but I want to ensure proper naming convention. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a hostname versus a computer name versus a subdomain versus www?](https://superuser.com/questions/887173/what-is-a-hostname-versus-a-computer-name-versus-a-subdomain-versus-www)

Comment: In my opinion, the PC name and computer name you mentioned should be the same thing. You could refer to this thread: [Difference between NETBIOS, host name and computer name?](https://superuser.com/questions/368602/difference-between-netbios-host-name-and-computer-name)